# How to upscript text in Powerpoint 2003?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2003, text-formatting

For some reason I can't find the menu that does that.
Is it even possible in that version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the text you want to format
   as superscript or subscript.
2. On the Format menu, click Font.
3. Select the Superscript or
   Subscript check box.